# Summernote: Enter key not working

Tags: jquery

I'm using summernote (http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/features.html) text editor in conjunction with jquery and jquery forms.

Actually there are other libraries implemented.

Thing is when enter key is pressed nothing happens.

Is there a solution / patch for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a script somewhere that is disabling the Enter key.  This is often done in forms to prevent accidental form submission when the user hits enter.  If there is a form on the page, inspect the scripts loaded to see if there is an onKeyPress even handler that is checking for something like this:

```
$('html').bind('keypress', function(e)
{
   if(e.keyCode == 13)
   {
      return false;
   }
});
```

If so, that's your problem.

Comment: I'm having this issue with the arrow keys in summernote and it did not resolve my issue. I also had to use the `keydown` event instead of `keypress` to capture the arrow key press.

Answer (score 0):

There is "callback" events to catch key events on summernote editor. But summernote has only keyup and keydown events.

**// onKeydown callback**

```
$('#summernote').summernote({

      callbacks: {
    
        onKeydown: function(e) {
          console.log('Key is downed:', e.keyCode);
        }
      }
    });
```

**// summernote.keydown**

```
$('#summernote').on('summernote.keydown', function(we, e) {

  console.log('Key is downed:', e.keyCode);

});
```